# Team City Build Failure Restoring .NET Standard

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to set up a build configuration for an ASP.NET Core (built on .NET full framework 4.6.2) project.

I'm Using TeamCity Enterprise 2017.2.3 (build 51047)

The .NET Core SDK is installed on the build server, along with 4.6.2 of the .NET Framework.

I am getting the following Build Error Message:

> ... This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets.

Anyone come across this error before?

I added the latest recommended Nuget exe (4.6.2) as well.

The build step upon which it is failing is a `.NET CLI (dotnet)` step.
I've set the `Command` to build
and the `Projects` to the Solution file.

Dotnet CLI is definitely installed and is **version 2.1.300**

Answer (score 0):

Yeah update the build tools on the TeamCity server, you're probably using the latest Visual Studio version on your local machine but your build tools on the build server are slightly out of date, probably earlier than v15.5.

https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15

Also ensure that you have selected to add the .NET Core 2(+) build tools as they include the .NETStandard and aren't selected by default. See https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/458#issuecomment-323845208